# Alipay payments fail with "The order data cannot be recognized..."

Tags: stripe-payments, alipay

My customers are getting the following error message while trying to pay using Alipay: 订单信息无法识别,建议联系卖家 which translates to "The order information cannot be recognized, it is recommended to contact the seller". Here's a screenshot sent by a client who tried to make a payment:

[image]

On the Payments tab, I get a lot of these:

> An attempt to fulfil the payment pi_1IjEunFotp...ZOgn6o for CN¥34.45 failed evt_1IjFr2...Se3s4 23/04/2021, 04:38:56

The purchase cycle works OK in test mode.

I contacted Stripe support and they got back to me with a lengthy email that might as well have been written by GPT-3. At times it went into details of what 3D Secure is and how it works. Overall it contained zero new information and no one even cared to look at the underlying cause.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Does this happen for *all* live mode payments, or just some? If it's all of them, is your account enabled for Alipay in live mode? If it's only some, are there any common factors? Most likely you'll need to work with Stripe support to explain a precise reproduction sequence for their engineers to review.

Comment: @NolanH, I received a few hundred attempts, all of them show as failed / cancelled. Stripe support have confirmed that Alipay is enabled for my account. Waiting to hear from them.

Comment: Got another response from Stripe support. Now they are saying that "Software and SaaS" is a prohibited business under Alipay rules. The page they link to does not say anything about "Software and SaaS". What does a developer need to do to get a decent error message??

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly same error message when integrating Alipay through Stripe. Contacting Alipay customer support revealed: the reason was that our production type (virtual product without shipping) was not approved by Alipay's registration process. So it's not Stripe's problem, just it's not allowed by Alipay side.

My guess is that virtual products may not be allowed to use Alipay oversea under some Chinese gov's regulations.

Comment: A few days ago (after about a month), Stripe support emailed me saying my Alipay onboarding had been successful. I have been able to receive payments since then. My business is also virtual products (subscriptions) without shipping.

Comment: @SergeySlepov how did you get subscriptions working in prod? I'm also approved, but following https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/alipay just results in an infinite loop asking the customer to keep confirming the subscription.